# d3js Force Layout: null values for node and link positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working through this [d3js force layout tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/26648f33f3bc9725604a), with some custom modifications. Mostly, my interest is to introduce an abstraction layer between my back-end and d3.js visualization, which I am doing using JS classes. Right now I am mostly throwing away some attributes I have in my mock .json file, but this logic could grow to be more complex.

Here is a MWE that I cannot seem to get to work:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/model.js"></script>
    <script src="js/viz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`model.js`:

```
class Node {

    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.outEdges = {};
        this.inEdges = {};
    }

}

class Edge {

    constructor(node1, node2) {
        this.source = node1;
        this.target = node2;
    }

}

class Graph {

    constructor(nodes, edges) {
        this.nodes = {}
        for (let node of nodes) {
            this.nodes[node.id] = node;
        }
        for (let edge of edges) {
            this.nodes[edge.source].outEdges[edge.target] = edge;
            this.nodes[edge.target].inEdges[edge.source] = edge;
        }
        this.edges = edges;
    }

}
```

`viz.js`:

```
function loadJson() {
    path = "mockup2.json";
    $.getJSON(path, function(json) {
        var nodes = [];
        var edges = [];

        for (let node of json.nodes) {
            var temp = new Node(node.index, node.name);
            nodes.push(temp);
        }
        for (let edge of json.edges) {
            var temp = new Edge(edge.node1, edge.node2);
            edges.push(temp);
        }
        var graph = new Graph(nodes, edges);

        drawGraph(graph);
    });
}

function drawGraph(graph) {
    width = "90%";
    height = "90%";

    // set up svg and layout
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                               .attr("width", width)
                               .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
                  .gravity(.1)
                  .distance(20)
                  .charge(-30)
                  .size([width, height]);

    // prep nodes and links for d3 viz
    var d3nodes = [];
    var temp = {};
    for (var key in graph.nodes) {
        node = graph.nodes[key]
        temp = {}
        temp.x = Math.random() * 100;
        temp.y = Math.random() * 100;
        temp.index = node.id;
        d3nodes.push(temp);
    }

    d3edges = [];
    var temp = {}
    for (var key in graph.edges) {
        edge = graph.edges[key];
        temp = {}
        temp.source = edge.source;
        temp.target = edge.target;
        temp.timediff = edge.timediff;
        d3edges.push(temp);
    }

    // draw links and nodes
    var svglinks = svg.selectAll('.link')
                        .data(d3edges)
                        .enter().append('line')
                        .attr('class', 'link');

    var svgnodes = svg.selectAll('.node')
            .data(d3nodes)
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .call(force.drag);

    force.nodes(d3nodes)
         .links(d3edges)
         .linkDistance(width/3)
         .start();

    // test svglinks values
    svglinks.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
    });

    force.on("tick", function() {
        svglinks.attr("x1", function(d) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
                            return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        svgnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

        // avoid console spam
        force.stop();
    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {
    loadJson();
});
```

`mockup2.json`:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"index": 0, "name": 0, "timestamp": 1, "group": 1},
    {"index": 1, "name": 0, "timestamp": 0, "group": 2},
    {"index": 2, "name": 0, "timestamp": 0, "group": 3},
    {"index": 3, "name": 0, "timestamp": 2, "group": 1},
    {"index": 4, "name": 0, "timestamp": 0, "group": 2},
    {"index": 5, "name": 0, "timestamp": 3, "group": 3},
    {"index": 6, "name": 0, "timestamp": 2, "group": 3},
    {"index": 7, "name": 0, "timestamp": 5, "group": 2},
    {"index": 8, "name": 0, "timestamp": 8, "group": 2},
    {"index": 9, "name": 0, "timestamp": 3, "group": 1}
  ],
  "edges": [
    {"node1": 1, "node2": 2},
    {"node1": 2, "node2": 4},
    {"node1": 4, "node2": 8},
    {"node1": 4, "node2": 8},
    {"node1": 8, "node2": 2},
    {"node1": 5, "node2": 9}
  ]
}
```

The most damning thing to me is that the `svglinks` variable seems to be fine before outside of the `force.on('tick')` stuff, displaying sane values for `x`, `y`, `px` and `py` - I have included a `console.log()` call for you to check this too. However, printing the very same object inside of that function shows me `null` values for all these attributes, which make it possible for d3.js to render the graph correctly (at least in my intuition).

I also have a more "standard" example which uses the more standard `d3.json()` call to load a .json file which is preformatted with `source` and `target` attributes; this works perfectly. So my intuition is that I am not properly building the `d3nodes` and `d3links` variables above; however, comparing them across examples has shown me that they look exactly the same. I am a little dumbfounded here, I will admit!

Thanks in advance to everyone who is going to take the time to give this a go.

Comment: the code as presented does not run at all. fix it first. dev-console will tell you what the problem is

Comment: @rioV8 done. thanks for the heads-up

Comment: why build a class tree based on a JSON file and from that you build a JSON data structure. have a closer look at your `width` and `height`. what do you want to show for a `node`? how are you going to show the links? what is the use of those `temp` vars?

Comment: @rioV8 as I explained in the question, my idea is to build an abstraction layer between what my back-end will return - could be a .json file, could be table rows. could you explain what you mean by "taking a look at width and height"? I am fine with the node just being small circles with no additional info ATM. I do know that I miss some CSS to get the links to show up, but that's not my cause for concern ATM, thanks though! the ```temp``` vars are just... temp variables that hold different objects when I build my nodes and links arrays.

Comment: where do you use them? that is the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, what is 'them'? If you have understood what is the issue in this code, could you please write it down as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: **them** is `width` and `height`

Comment: thanks, this is working now. if you want to write it down as answer I will accept it.